# dereferencing pointers using "this"

Tags: c++, class, pointers, this, dereference

I am trying to call a variable in my class using the this keyword in two ways but I am confused with the 2nd way. The correct way of dereferencing happens to be "(*this).num" however, *I* was wondering why "*(this).num" is not right as well. The error I get with *(this).num is

*request for member 'num' in 'this', which is of pointer type çlass* const'*

```
class::class(int n): num(n)
{
cout << "num= " << num << endl;
cout << "this->num" << this->num << endl;
cout << "(*this).num" << (*this).num << endl;
}
```

Because if you define

```
int i = 9;
int *ptr = &i;
cout<<*(ptr)<<endl;
```

and call *(ptr) it works. But why doesn't it work in my class?

Comment: Your code differs from the question I. Ed.  Location of brackets

Comment: My question is about why the astrick needs to be inside the brackets in the class while on the other hand, in another completely different scenario the astrick outside the bracket doesn't matter. I get its something to do with calling the "num" variable in my class but don't know the excat reason @EdHeal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a matter of operator precedence. The binary dot operator has a higher precedence than the unary star operator, so `*(this).num` (the parentheses have no effect there) is interpreted as `*(this.num)`, and not as `(*this).num`. The compiler is telling you that, because `this` is a pointer, `this.num` doesn't make sense: you can't apply the dot operator directly to a pointer.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I get it, first dereference then add .num.

Answer (score 1):

`.` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `*`.

So writing `*(this).num` is equivalent to `(*((this).num)))`. Or `*(this.num)`.

Your second example is completely different from the first since there is no access to members `.` or `->`.

If you don't know all the precedences, or even if you do, it's usually more readable to add the appropriate brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two operators: the indirection/dereferincing operator `*` and the member access operator `.`.

If you have a look at [the precedence of these operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), you'll see that `.` has higher precedence than `*` (that is, `.` will be applied before `*`), so thus `*(this).num` is basically the same as writing `*(this.num)`.

Since `this` is a pointer, you can't use the `.` operator on it, which is also what the error message is telling you (try using `->` instead).

The reason why your second example works, is that you're not using the `.` operator, and thus there is no precedence to be messed up.

Answer (score 1):

One works and the other doesn't because they are not the same thing!

`*(ptr)` and `*(this)` are the same, but `*(this).num` and `(*this).num` are not the same, *that's the whole point of adding the parentheses!*  They change how the sub-expressions are grouped, just like in mathematics.

The parentheses in `(ptr)` and `(this)` are completely redundant, you are grouping a single sub-expression, which does nothing.  In `(*this)` it's not redundant, it ensures that you dereference the pointer, so in `(*this).num` it dereferences the pointer first and *then* the member access `.num` is applied to the result of that dereference.

Compare it to mathematics:

(1) is just 1, and similarly `(ptr)` is just `ptr`

-(1) is just -1, and similarly `*(ptr)` is just `*ptr`

But -(1 + 3) and -(1) + 3 are completely different, because you change the order of the operators.

Similarly, `*(this.num)` and `(*this).num` are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is syntax.

*(ptr) looks like this: evaluate expr inside () first, then dereference the result which is in this case is int*. It's fine, the same as *ptr.

*(this).num is eq. with *this.num which means get the num member of this. After that dereference num. It's incorrect as you can see because "this" is a pointer to the current object.

(*this).num means dereference this, then get the num member.